# How do I include a file that is not a .h, .c or .cpp file?

Tags: spi

I am using the ADF7030 on the breakout board (not motherboard) and I am trying to interface it with an Arduino Uno. I want to load the transceivers configuration file onto the chip using SPI. To do this, I need to include the ".cfg" file but when I use the C style array (as in the datasheet - code below) it says that it can't find the file in the .ino sketch.

`const unit8_t Radio_Memory_Configuration [ ] = {
     #include "Settings_ADF7030-1.cfg"
}`

How could I include this file?

Comment: I guess the Arduino IDE preprocessor is making it difficult for you. As it copies files to a build directory it might miss your specific configuration file. Try changing the file suffix to .h just to test this.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the [arduino-builder source](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder) only files with the following extensions are copied to the build directory: .ino .pde .h .c .hpp .hh .cpp .s

So you will need to use one of those extensions.